# Kafka s3 connector to minio in parquet format

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, avro, parquet, apache-kafka-connect

I use docker compose to start 3 services in their respect containers:
zookeeper, kafka broker, and minio-connector

The three services can be started and connected successfully when I use the following configurations in minio-connector to consume from kafka and dump record in JSON format to minio:

1. start up command:

`root@e1d1294c6fe6:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin# ./connect-standalone.sh /plugins/connector.properties /plugins/s3-sink.properties`

2. connector.properties file:

```
    bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092
    plugin.path=/plugins
    key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
    value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
    internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
    internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
    offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
```

3. s3-sink.properties file:

```
    name=s3-sink 
    connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector    
    tasks.max=1 
    topics=202208.minio.connector.test 
    s3.region=us-east-1   
    s3.bucket.name=minioUsr 
    s3.part.size=5242880 
    flush.size=1    
    store.url=https://minio.kube.url    
    storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage    
    format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat   
    schema.compatibility=NONE 
    schema.generator.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator    
    partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
```

Now I'd like the connector to consume records and dump to minio in parquet format.
kafka and zookeeper services remain the same. I modified the connector.properties and s3-sink.properties but the connector cannot start.

4. new connector.properties file:

```
    bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092
    plugin.path=/plugins
    internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
    internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
    offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
    key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    key.converter.schemas.enable=false
    value.converter.schemas.enable=true
    key.converter.schema.registry.url=https://registry...:1443
    value.converter.schema.registry.url=https://registry...:1443
```

5. new s3-sink.properties:

```
    name=s3-sink
    connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
    tasks.max=1
    topics=202208.minio.connector.test
    s3.region=us-east-1
    s3.bucket.name=minioUsr
    s3.part.size=5242880
    flush.size=1
    store.url=https://minio.kube.url
    storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
    schema.generator.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator
    partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
    schema.compatibility=NONE
    format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat
    enhanced.avro.schema.support=true
```

My questions are:
With the above configuration, the connector fails to start with an exception

```
    [2022-08-29 15:21:10,610] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:130)
    org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter for configuration value.converter: Class
    io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter could not be found.
            at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:728)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:474)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:467)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:108)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:129)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.<init>(WorkerConfig.java:385)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneConfig.<init>(StandaloneConfig.java:42)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:81)
```

I installed the connector by downloading the confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-10.1.0 zip file and manually unzip and copy all jars to /plugins/lib. I found the following jars related to parquet:

```
    root@e1d1294c6fe6:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin# ls -1 /plugins/lib/*parquet*
    /plugins/lib/parquet-avro-1.11.1.jar
    /plugins/lib/parquet-column-1.11.1.jar
    /plugins/lib/parquet-common-1.11.1.jar
    /plugins/lib/parquet-encoding-1.11.1.jar
    /plugins/lib/parquet-format-structures-1.11.1.jar
    /plugins/lib/parquet-hadoop-1.11.1.jar
```

What is missing in installation?
Any further change is required in the configuration?

Comment: I do see AvroConverters, AvroRecordConverter  classes in /plugins/lib/parquet-avro-1.11.1.jar instead of AvroConvert.  so which convert class name should I use?

Answer (score 1):

I have to manually install avro converter using confluent-hub

1. download confluent-hub client:
   https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.1/connect/managing/confluent-hub/client.html
2. using confluent-hub to install avro converter, following answers in:
   [Kafka Connect Confluent S3 Sink Connector: Class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441231/kafka-connect-confluent-s3-sink-connector-class-io-confluent-connect-avro-avroc)